# Using view instead of its own code inside another view slows down the performance

Tags: mysql

After years of working with MYSQL databases, this is the first time I've come across such weird behaviour. Best described by example.

View A.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `edgar`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `v_price_list` AS
    SELECT ...
    FROM table_a
    INNER JOIN view_b ON ....
```

This view is critically slow (it takes me so long to perform a select-query that I don't have patience enough to wait until it finishes).

But if I take the code of `view_b` and insert it in the definition of `view_a`, it's ok. I've tried to set `ALGORITHM = MERGE`, but nothing has changed. 
What could be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: Have you had a look at the explain plan for this?

Comment: All of the `keys` and `possible_keys` have non-null values indicating that there are indexes used for the relation. No surprise because I'm using foreign keys everywhere throughout database

Comment: Would you care to include some statistics such as number of rows and result set size?  I am thinking aloud here (guessing - :) ):  Sometimes indexes can actually make the query slower as the engine has to do multiple reads for each row. It also depends on disk cache size, memory etc. i.e if most of the rows in a table are required then the index doesn't help. You know this already. Just stating the obvious. ;-/ I have no idea how much analysis you have dome with this query.

Comment: Willl provide it soon